# how to call different static blocks in product detail page according to category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I want to call different-2 static blocks in product detail page "**ACCORDING TO CATEGORY**".

```
Lets say i have 2 categories :

1.electronics
2.mobiles
```

In elecronics category, i want to show a different static block at a specific section.And in mobiles category, i want to show a different static block at the same specific section.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could create static blocks in the backend and name those as `category_static_block_1`,  `category_static_block_2` etc. where these are to show in category id 1 and 2 respectively, you may use the below code in your `.phtml` file to do this.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('category_static_block_'+$catid)->toHtml() ?>
```

Here the `$cat_id` should contain the current categories id.